# Desaparecer duas divs com jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Antes de mais nada eu fiz um foreach no meu banco mas o código ficará muito extenso continuando,
Oque eu quero fazer é com que o usuário clique no link apareça uma confirmacão de uma div, 
nesta div terá um link para deletar realmente o artigo o problema é quando eu deleto o artigo,
 a div do artigo nao desaparece só some a div da janela-moldal, e eu gostaria que essa janela de confirmacão
 apareça somente em cima da div clicada. agradeço a todos que me ajudar e criticas construtivas serão bem-vindas

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){

$('.excluir').click(function(){
    $('.janela-moldal').fadeIn();
});

$('.chamar-moldal').click(function(){
    $('.janela-moldal').fadeIn();
});

$('.cancelar').click(function(){
    $('.janela-moldal').fadeOut();
});

$(".excluir-artigo").live('click',function(){
         $.post('php/deletar.php', {coment:$(this).attr('id')});
         $(this).parent('div').fadeOut();
      $(".janela-moldal").fadeOut();
    };
});

});


</script>

<?php
    $artigo[] = array();
    $artigo['artigo_id'] = 1;
    $artigo['frase'] = '"A vingança nunca é plena, mata a alma e a invenena"';
?>


<div class="artigos" id="artigos"> 
    <?=$artigo['artigo_id']; ?>
    <h1><?= $artigo['frase']; ?></h1>
    <a class="chamar-moldal" href="javascript:void(0);">chamar a div de confirmacão </a>
</div>

<div class="janela-moldal" style="display:none"> 
    <h1>Deseja excluir este artigo?</h1>
    <a class="cancelar" href="javascript:void(0);">cancelar</a>
    <a class="excluir-artigo" id="artigo-<?=$artigo['artigo_id']?>" href="javascript:void(0);">excluir</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloque a Modal dentro da div do artigo

```
<div class="artigos" id="artigos"> 
    <?=$artigo['artigo_id']; ?>
    <h1><?= $artigo['frase']; ?></h1>
    <a class="chamar-moldal" href="javascript:void(0);">chamar a div de confirmacão </a>

    <div class="janela-moldal" style="display:none"> 
        <h1>Deseja excluir este artigo?</h1>
        <a class="cancelar" href="javascript:void(0);">cancelar</a>
        <a class="excluir-artigo" id="artigo-<?=$artigo['artigo_id']?>" href="javascript:void(0);">excluir</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

E na hora de remover, chame parent() duas vezes.

```
$(".excluir-artigo").live('click',function(){
     $.post('php/deletar.php', {coment:$(this).attr('id')});
     $(this).parent('div').parent('div').fadeOut();  // VOcê pode fazer assim
     //$(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();   // Ou assim
     $(".janela-moldal").fadeOut();
    };
});
```